# How can I check if a server is up in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I am trying to create a dedicated server. I can join but I want to know if it is available online for my friends. Is there any tool for this?

Comment: you could add it to your favourites list in game or get your friend to add it to their favourites list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use http://www.canyouseeme.org/ . Just enter the port, 27015, and the website will try to connect to your server to see if the port is open or blocked by your ISP, forwarded (if you are behind a router) and accepting connections.

Comment: both TCP 27015 and UDP 27015 seems to be working. tried adding +net_public_adr and +sv_lan 0 but couldnt get it work. thanks anyway

Comment: @emmett Try +sv_lan "0" sometimes the syntax can getcha.

Answer (score 5):

you should use

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetServersAtAddress/v0001?addr=<your ip here>&format=xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I can add the server that I created, to game monitoring web sites such as gametracker, game-monitor, game-state.. if the server is  up and running. and I can monitor from there.